# Java BufferedOutputStream: How many bytes to write

Tags: java, download, bufferedinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

This is more like a matter of conscience than a technological issue :p
I'm writing some java code to dowload files from a server...For that, i'm using the BufferedOutputStream method write(), and BufferedInputStream method read().

So my question is, if i use a buffer to hold the bytes, what should be the number of bytes to read? Sure i can read byte to byte using just int byte = read() and then write(byte), or i could use a buffer. If i take the second approach, is there any aspects that i must pay attention when defining the number of bytes to read\write each time? What will this number affect in my program?

Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a really fast network connection, the size of the buffer will make little difference.  I'd say that 4k buffers would be fine, though there's no harm in using buffers a bit bigger.

The same probably applies to using `read()` versus `read(byte[])` ... assuming that you are using a `BufferedInputStream`.

Unless you have an extraordinarily fast / low-latency network connection, the bottleneck is going to be the data rate that the network and your computers' network interfaces can sustain.  For a typical internet connection, the application can move the data two or more orders of magnitude  of times faster than the network can.  So unless you do something silly (like doing 1 byte reads on an unbuffered stream), your Java code won't be the bottleneck.

Comment: First to answer, and with a good answer :p  I'll set the size of the buffer between 1024-4096. Thks

Answer (score 1):

BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream typically rely on System.arraycopy for their implementations. System.arraycopy has a native implementation, which likely relies on memmove or bcopy. The amount of memory that is copied will depend on the available space in your buffer, but regardless, the implementation down to the native code is pretty efficient, unlikely to affect the performance of your application regardless of how many bytes you are reading/writing.

However, with respect to BufferedInputStream, if you set a mark with a high limit, a new internal buffer may need to be created. If you do use a mark, reading more bytes than are available in the old buffer may cause a temporary performance hit, though the amortized performance is still linear.

As Stephen C mentioned, you are more likely to see performance issues due to the network.

Comment: Your response is valid too, but since Stephen C was the first to reply, he is the winner :p Thks anyway.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues: Not worried about "winning" :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is the MTU(maximum traffic unit) in your network connection? If you using UDP for example, you can check this value and use smaller array of bytes. If this is no metter, you need to check how memory eats your program. I think `1024 - 4096` will be good variant to save this data and continue to receive

Comment: I can't rely on the MTU, because this program will be executed from different networks. I'll set the size of the buffer between 1024-4096 although. Thks.

Answer (score 0):

If you pump data you normally do not need to use any Buffered streams. Just make sure you use a decently sized (8-64k) temporary byte[] buffer passed to the read method (or use a pump method which does it). The default buffer size is too small for most usages (and if you use a larger temp array it will be ignored anyway)